# How can I remove seperate worker thread function and create a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is the traditional thread creation code:

```
        public static void Ping()
        {
            new Thread(workThreadPingRequest) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
        }

        private static void workThreadPingRequest()
        {
           line1(); //Create connection
           line2(); //Ask ping
           line3(); //Process the reply and close connection
        }
```

I've got many pairs like them. So how can I remove seperate worker thread function to make the code easier -to me- like below:

```
        public static void Ping()
        {
            new Thread(new Func<void> fn = () => 
                { line1(); line2(); line3();}) 
                { IsBackground = true }
                .Start();
        }
```

Or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using .NET 4's [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    line1();
    line2();
    line3();
});
```

Comment: Lines are synchronous, aren't they?

Comment: @Nime: I'm not sure what you mean. The anonymous function (`() => {   }`) will run synchronously, but on a separate thread. So `line1`, `line2`, and `line3` will all get run one after another on the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

@Cameron's answer seems like an excellent idea but if are on .net 3.5 you could use the threadpool instead:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        line1();
        line2();
        line3();
    });
```

Also if you really want create a new thread instead you can do this:

```
new Thread(() => 
{
    line1();
    line2();
    line3();
}) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

Comment: 2nd is the answer of my question. All of the snippets are aweome too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are just interested in syntax enhancement?  BackgroundWorker is pretty convienent.

```
string arg = "blah...";
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (s,e) =>
{
// can extract args from e
// code here
};
worker.RunAsync(args);
```

this code is off the top of my head so it might not be perfect, but the idea is there.